# Dynamic Linq on DataTable error: no Field or Property in DataRow, c#

Tags: linq, datatable

I have some errors using Linq on DataTable and I couldn't figure it out how to solve it. I have to admit that i am pretty new to Linq and I searched the forum and Internet and couldn't figure it out. hope you can help.

I have a DataTable called `campaign` with three columns: `ID` (int), `Product` (string), `Channel` (string). The DataTable is already filled with data. I am trying to select a subset of the campaign records which satisfied the conditions selected by the end user. For example, the user want to list only if the Product is either 'EWH' or 'HEC'. The selection criteria is dynaically determined by the end user.

I have the following C# code:

```
private void btnClick()
{
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
                from zz in campaign.AsEnumerable()
                orderby zz.Field<string>("ID")
                select zz;
string whereClause = "zz.Field<string>(\"Product\") in ('EWH','HEC')";
query = query.Where(whereClause);
DataTable sublist = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
}
```

But it gives me an error on line: `query = query.Where(whereClause)`, saying

> No  property or field 'zz' exists in type 'DataRow'".

If I changed to: 
    `string whereClause = "Product in ('EWH','HEC')";` it will say:

> No property or field 'Product' exists in type 'DataRow'

Can anyone help me on how to solve this problem? I feel it could be a pretty simple syntax change, but I just don't know at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line has an error

```
orderby zz.Field<string>("ID")
```

because as you said, your `ID` column is of type `int`.

Second, you need to learn LINQ query syntax. Forget about strings, the same way you used `from`, `orderby`, `select` in the query, you can also use `where` and many other operators. Also you'll need to learn the equivalent LINQ constructs for SQL-ish things, like for instance `IN (...)` is mapped to [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).aspx) etc.

With all that being said, here is your query

```
var productFilter = new[] { "EWH", "HEC" };
var query =
    from zz in campaign.AsEnumerable()
    where productFilter.Contains(zz.Field<string>("Product"))
    orderby zz.Field<int>("ID")
    select zz;
```

**Update** As per your comment, if you want to make this dynamic, then you need to switch to lambda syntax. Multiple `and` criteria can be composed by chaining multiple `Where` clauses like this

```
List<string> productFilter = ...; // coming from outside
List<string> channelFilter = ...; // coming from outside
var query = campaign.AsEnumerable();
// Apply filters if needed
if (productFilter != null && productFilter.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(zz => productFilter.Contains(zz.Field<string>("Product")));
if (channelFilter != null && channelFilter.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(zz => channelFilter.Contains(zz.Field<string>("Channel")));
// Once finished with filtering, do the ordering
query = query.OrderBy(zz => zz.Field<int>("ID"));
```

Comment: Ivan, this very helpful. As you pointed out, the ID should be int. In your code, you use the productFilter to only keep the desired entries. It works as expected. However, another hurdle is the user may not apply any productFilter at all or they have filter on Channel or any combinations of multiple filters (I only list Product and Channel as examples in my original post). How do I dynamically set the WHERE clause?

Comment: This continues my comment because there is length constraints. I can build a long string to dynamically concat filters such as: 'string whereClause="productFilter.Contains(zz.Field<string>("Product")) and channelFilter.Contains(zz.Field<string>("Channel"))', but I cannot put this variable following WHERE because it expects some specified conditions instead of a string variable although the expression of the string is the conditions. Not sure if I made the problem clear. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @sguo I've updated the answer with an example of dynamic filtering. Hope that works for you.